# Change VS C++ compilar to vc 11 to vc12

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I complied boost library by using vc 12 but my visual studio has vc 11. when I try to run boost sample program which is used boost (c++ library ) visual studio 2013 shows `cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib`   my libray path -(..\boost_1_54_0 2\stage\lib) im having `libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_54` . think that issue I can solve by changing visual studio complier vc11 to vc12. how do I do that please help me.

Comment: How can you have VC12 without Visual Studio? Are you using Visual C++ Express Edition?

Comment: @Dai have both 2012 and 2013 visual studio 2013 I have Ultimate. can you please drop me a way to change the vc11 to vc 12

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is compiler or OS related dependency, you can solve it by linking with appropriate library. Check the setting of your project. Where, it was expecting vc110 library, change it to corresponding vc120 library.
If it does not work (because of some other issues like compiler specific problem, platform specific problem, or duplicate symbols as it was linked with different C runtime library), you can try the following:

1. Rebuild boost but with dynamic CRT library (instead of static library) (check /MD or /MT option). In this way, you need not to change either of compiler.
2. If nothing works, build both application and library using same compiler.